# Addtion and Scalar multiplication closure

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that V = $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of real numbers and F = $\mathbb{R}$ is the field of scalars. Define operations of addition $\oplus$ and scalar multiplication $\odot$ as follows:

$$x ⊕ y = x + y + 1 \ \ and \ \ α \odot x = αx + α − 1$$
for all x, y ∈ V and all α ∈ $\mathbb{R}$.

(a) Show that V is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Solution:

For any a, b ∈ V: $$a + b = a+b+1$$ Since, $a+b+1∈ V$, it is closed under addition.

For any a ∈ V: $$α\odot a = αa + α-1$$ Since $αa + α-1 ∈ V$, it is closed under scalar multiplication.

(b) Show that there is a zero vector $0$ in V satisfying vector space axiom A4.

Solution:

$0∈ V$ and for any $a∈ V$, $a+0 = a$

(c) Find an additive inverse for x ∈ V satisfying vector space axiom A5.

Solution:

$-x$ satisfies axiom A5: $$x + (-x) = 0$$ for all x ∈ V.

Can someone please verify if this is enough for proving the required axioms in the question.

EDIT (based on Joe's Suggestions):

b) solution:

For any a ∈ V:
$$a ⊕ (-1) = a + (-1) + 1 = a$$, for $0$ vector: -1

c) solution:

For any a ∈ V: $$ a ⊕ (-a-2) = a + (-a-2) + 1 = -1$$

Comment: b & c are not correct. You need to find the additive identity and inverse for the operations defined in your problem. Hint for (b): what does $y$ need to be for the RHS to equal $x$?

Comment: @Joe thank you so much for pointing out my errors. Can you please have a look again and see if it's okay this time round?

Comment: For part (a), rather than simply say “Since $a+b+1 \in V$”, your professor may want you to explicitly say that $a+b+1 \in \mathbb{R}$ because $\mathbb{R}$ is closed under addition. Basically, you’re using the fact that the usual addition and multiplication are closed in $\mathbb{R}$, to prove that addition and scalar multiplication are closed in $V$.

Comment: b is correct now, although instead of writing $a=a$, you should just append $=a$ onto the end of previous equation.  Also there’s a circle plus in that equation that should just be plus.  Your c isn’t yet correct.  What do you need to add to $a$ to get the zero vector $-1$?

Comment: @Joe do we have to find an additive inverse such that the addition results in -1 in this case (because the zero vector is -1) or does it have to equal 0 every time?

Comment: @Joe I have changed it to reflect additive inverse resulting in the zero vector calculated in b. I had previously assumed that additive inverse means it should result in 0.

Comment: Good job, yes, those are correct, although you should probably explicitly state, therefore $-a-2$ is the additive inverse of $a$.

Comment: Done. Thank you!

Comment: You’are welcome